# Keras CNN Coordinate Regression Only Gives Mean Value

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, keras, regression

I have been trying to implement a CNN that, given a (75x75) image of a detector, will output the (x,y) coordinate of the source for that image. Each image has features that make it possible to determine the source. The issue I am coming up with is that the regressor, which outputs the x, y coordinate, always returns the mean pixel value for all the training data. I've tried to implement the regressor outlined in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10698 but it still gives the mean pixel value as all the predictions. A short version of my model is here:

```
model = Sequential()

# Base Conv layer
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=patch_size, strides=(1, 1),
                    activation='relu', padding='same',
                    input_shape=(75, 75, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, patch_size, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding=optimizer))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
for i in range(num_conv):
    model.add(Conv2D(64, patch_size, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, patch_size, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())

for i in range(num_dense):
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='linear'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_layer))


# Final Dense layer
# 2 so have one for x and one for y
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
```

I don't have the rep to post images of the sources, but here is truth and outputs when it is trained on 42000 images:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/63ufMqp.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6eou.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qzZ5.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE9QF.png]

As you can see, its horribly off, all the estimations are in that one dot at the mean value of all the x,y coordinates. while the actual values create a circle covering the whole detector. I am not sure how to get it to actually output correct values. I get that the mean squared error as the loss probably should make the estimation the center value, as it is the minimum squared distance from all the sources, but I am not sure how else to try it, since I want to minimize the distance between each prediction and its label individually.